# MySQL Declaration PHPMyADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, declaration

Im want to run queries with declaraions in PHPMYADMIN.

Here my querycode

```
declare @shopdomain varchar(30);
SET @shopdomain = 'newdomain.com';
UPDATE trans SET tval=REPLACE(name,'olddomain.de', @shopdomain ) WHERE name LIKE 'olddomain.de';
UPDATE settings SET tval=REPLACE(name,'olddomain.de', @shopdomain ) WHERE name LIKE 'olddomain.de';
UPDATE...
```

PHPMYADMIN shows this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare @shopdomain varchar(30)' at line 1
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html

Comment: I believe you need DECLARE shopadmin varchar(30) DEFAULT 'newdomain.com' (without the @)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `DECLARE` available **only** in a context of a stored routine (procedure, function, trigger, event)
2. You're mixing local variables (without `@` in front of their names) with user(session) variables

That being said if you want to go with local variables you do something like this

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE shopdomain VARCHAR(30);
  SET shopdomain = 'newdomain.com';
  UPDATE trans SET tval = REPLACE(name,'olddomain.de', shopdomain ) WHERE name LIKE 'olddomain.de';
  UPDATE settings SET tval=REPLACE(name,'olddomain.de', shopdomain ) WHERE name LIKE 'olddomain.de';
  UPDATE ...
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then call your procedure

```sql
CALL my_proc();
```

If you go with session variables then you can execute it right away without creating a procedure in the following manner

```sql
SET @shopdomain = 'newdomain.com';
UPDATE trans SET tval = REPLACE(name,'olddomain.de', @shopdomain ) WHERE name LIKE 'olddomain.de';
UPDATE settings SET tval=REPLACE(name,'olddomain.de', @shopdomain ) WHERE name LIKE 'olddomain.de';
UPDATE ...
```